# Effects of wrong lidar calibration

Tags: lidar, calibration, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on calibrating the pose of some lidar relative to base_link frame. After Calibrating x,y and yaw angle of the lidar, I noticed that there is inconsistency in the data showed by the sensor. By increasing the decay time of the laser scans and rotating the robot in place (having a good odometry) this is what I see in Rviz:

[image: image description]

I also compared what the front and back lidar see and this is what I get:
[image: image description]

The robot is standing in a nearly rectangular area, what I find weird is that in one corner both laser are well aligned while on the other corner the deviation of the scans is huge.

I am wondering if this effect can be produced by a wrong calibration of x,y,yaw values or that it is the result of a tilted lasers not sharing the same scanning plane (roll and pitch are not equal to zero).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229991/effects-of-wrong-lidar-calibration/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean with "wrong calibration of x,y,yaw values" ? You performed a 3DoF calibration, but you need a full 6DoF calibration here. What you see is, without doubts, an issue caused by having different scanning planes. Which kind of robot are you using?

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-03-24**:
Yes well I assumed that the lasers are mounted horizontally, but I guess some error in the pitch and roll cannot be avoided, leading to different scanning planes. [The robot](http://www.magazino.eu/toru/) I work on is developed at the company where I work.

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2016-03-26**:
I had the same issues in my lab in the university ;-) You can't assume anything in this robotic-world!